# Return SQL results in new table and re-sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a SQL statement (for Microsoft SQL Server) which returns as a result:

- Column 1 = number active Users = [ActiveUser]
- Column 2 = Month as a Number = [InMonth]
- Column 3 = Airline ID = [AirlineCode]

What I would like to do now is create a new table and re-arrange the result in such a way that I get:

- Row = [AirlineCode]
- Column = Month
- Cells = number of active Users = [ActiveUser]

That's the query so far:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (DISTINCT AppUser.Id) as ActiveUser, 
    InMonth = DATEPART(month, ImportDate), 
    AirlineCode   
FROM 
    [db].[dbo].[AppUser] 
JOIN 
    [db].[dbo].[PlanDataVersion] ON AppUser.Id = PlanDataVersion.UserId
WHERE 
    ImportDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
GROUP BY  
    AirlineCode, DATEPART(month, ImportDate)
ORDER BY 
    InMonth, ActiveUser;
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [TSQL PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) query:

```
SELECT AirlineCode, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
FROM  
(
    SELECT
        COUNT (DISTINCT AppUser.Id) AS ActiveUser,
        DATEPART(month, ImportDate) AS InMonth,
        AirlineCode
    FROM
        [db].[dbo].[AppUser]
        JOIN [db].[dbo].[PlanDataVersion]
            ON AppUser.Id = PlanDataVersion.UserId
    WHERE ImportDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
    GROUP BY AirlineCode, DATEPART(month, ImportDate)
) AS Source
PIVOT  
(  
    SUM(ActiveUser)
    FOR InMonth IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY AirlineCode;
```

Be careful with date range tests if the dates are stored with a time part, since '2017-12-31' means '2017-12-31 12:00:00.000'! Therefore it is safer to compare

```
ImportDate >= '2017-01-01 00:00' AND ImportDate < '2018-01-01 00:00'
```

to include dates like '2017-12-31 23:59:59.500', i.e. half of a second before the end of the year. Otherwise dates after 12 AM on December 31 will not be included! See: [BETWEEN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-using-between-with-datetime-values).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) function.

SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT ManufacturerId, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]  
FROM  
(SELECT [Month], UserCount, ManufacturerId   
    FROM MyTable) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(UserCount)  
FOR [Month] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])  
) AS PivotTable;
```